# JSDuck: Specify an array of a certain length

Tags: extjs, jsduck

Using JSDuck for the documentation of my ExtJS application, I try to add a configuration that has to be String[8]:

```
/**
 * @cfg {String[8]} FooColors The eight colors to use for foo. All CSS color formats (Hex, RGB, RGBA, color names...) are valid.
 */
```

The error is

```
incorrect type syntax String[8]
```

Using `{String}` instead of `{String[8]}`, everything works; so the issue is the square brackets. But what syntax do I need to use?

I have not found any help in [the type definition docs](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/wiki/Type-Definitions).

Comment: Pretty sure it's not possible, you should just note the length in the docs (and perhaps validate it with a debug block in the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. That's not possible, and unlikely to be supported, as it's a fairly uncommon scenario to require an array of certain length. Just use `{String[]}` and simply document the required length with words.

I'd also suggest you seriously consider why do you need an array of 8 colors. Maybe an object with named keys for all these colors would be more appropriate, or maybe you could allow an arbitrary number of colors.